# Розовый фон в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Когда нажимаю на "Play" или на вкладку "Game", появляется розовый экран. Не создавал никаких объектов, есть только два объекта по умолчанию, и те не показываются, только розовый экран.

[image: Когда нажимаю на "Play" или на вкладку "Game", появляется розовый экран]

изменено: нету теней. Как не было, так и не появилось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Судя по версии Unity 5.6 (последняя 32 битная) вы запустили на старом компе. Видеокарта тоже старая и поддерживает только OpenGL 2-2.2 из-за чего она не может отрисовать шейдер старшей версии (розовый цвет это всегда не отобразившийся шейдер и не только в Unity).

В вашем случае не отображается `Skybox`. В настройках окна `Lighting` его можно убрать и использовать вариант с заливочным цветом.

Ошибка [SceneView Selected shader is expected to have 7 passes](https://forum.unity.com/threads/sceneview-selected-shader-is-expected-to-have-7-passes-unityeditor-dockarea-ongui.445363/?_ga=2.52233263.706120352.1600549494-555920994.1585235902) по той-же причине. Не может орисовать оконтовку выделения GameObject. Его можно отключить `Gizmos/Selection outline`
(сверху-справа окна сцены).

Comment: Сделал все как надо. Ошибка перестала выдаваться. Но есть вопрос: не повлияет ли это на дальнейшую разработку? Это же костылек, по-моему. И выглядит, кстати, не очень, но это я криворукий.

Comment: Никаких костылей.

Comment: нету теней. фото прикрепил в вопросе.